# problem regarding permutation.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations

There are 8 boys and 7 girls in a group. For each of the tasks specified below, write an
expression for the number of ways of doing it.

a) Sitting in a row so that all boys sit contiguously and all girls sit contiguously, i.e., no
girl sits between any two boys and no boy sits between any two girls

I Cant able find to the correct reasoning.please someone help.

Comment: "all boys sit contiguously and all girls sit contiguously" sounds like $8!\cdot7!\cdot2!$.

Comment: yes right but how sir,reason it please @barakmanos

Comment: "no girl sits between any two boys and no boy sits between any two girls" sounds **not equivalent** to the previous definition!!! Unless that row is a circle, something's fundamentally wrong with this question IMO.

Comment: no girl sits between **any** two boys and no boy sits between **any** two girls

Comment: @barakmanos : Yes, I first wrote an answer to the "all boys sit contiguously and all girls sit contiguously". This is just 8!7!2! by clumping them together in two groups, B and G. Saying "no girl sits between any two boys and no boy sits between any two girls" is saying that we could have girls/boys sitting together in pairs (or groups of n) for example (leaving one girl alone furthest out in the first case). You have to decide what the question is. EDIT: Sorry, saw your answer above first now Sathasivam, also therefore I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Christopher.L I think you're overthinking the question (because it's poorly worded). So I think your nicely written deleted answer is right and you should restore it.

Comment: @EthanBolker : The problem is that we seem to have gotten an answer above (directly from the OP), to what the question was about: "no girl sits between any two boys and no boy sits between any two girls". In this case my analysis in the comments above is correct, and thus my answer was wrong. Sathasivam, again, can you clarify that you have understood the difference and change your original question please? I will undelete my answer if it turns out to be correct.

Comment: @Christopher.L As long as the question contains the "contiguously" yours is the only way to read it. The "any two" in the "i.e" that follows is confusing and unnecessary. Let's see what the OP does.

Comment: i won't say between two boys there is girls but what i'm saying between **any** boys there is no girl.i want to emphasize the word **any ** in my context @Christopher.L

Comment: @EthanBolker i won't say between two boys there is girls but what i'm saying between **any** boys there is no girl.i want to emphasize the word **any ** in my context

Comment: So in short: BBBBBBBBGGGGGGG, GGGGGGGBBBBBBBB are the only sorts of arrangements you consider? You don't want to count GBBBBGGGGBBBBGG for example?

Comment: Yes @christopher

Comment: Ok, I'm going to assume you mean 'yes' to my first , and main, question and not to the followup. This could go on for ever otherwise.  It almost feels a bit late and unnecessary now, but then I will undelete my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what you do is to first realize that you may order the boys in $8!$ ways. Hopefully you already know how to reason here. (You may choose the first one in $8$ ways, the second in $7$ ways, and so on.)

The same reasoning goes for the girls, here we get $7!$ ways to sit them down.

Now for each order of boys, $8!$, you may order the girls in $7!$ ways, so by the rule of product you can sit them down in $8!7!$ ways.

Now, think of all boys/girls, sitting down in a row, as one group, call the groups $B$ for boys and $G$ for girls (you have $8!$ such boy groups, and $7!$ such girl groups). Then you have to take into account that you may order these two groups in $2!$ ways, namely $BG$ and $GB$. (This is because you couldn't mix the two groups up, because of the condition of boys/girls sitting contiguously by gender. You may only mix up the order of the groups.)

Again then, by rule of product, you have $8!7!2!$ ways in total.